# Ayuda con formato de fecha

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, datepicker

estoy tratando de usar el Datepicker de vuejs el cual en el v-model retorna la fecha en este formato "2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z" yo solo quiero obtener la fecha (en este caso sería "2015-03-04") ya que el campo de la base de datos de tipo "date" solo admite este ultimo, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Probaste transformarla al formato que queres en algun lado?

Comment: ese es el detalle, que no se cómo transformarla

Comment: Que yo sepa Vue.js no tiene un datepicker propio... Que libreria estas usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví lo unico que hice fue guardar la fecha que me daba el datepicker, formatearla y luego extraer lo que necesitaba, de la siguiente forma:

```
var d = new Date(this.crudeDate);
  var day = d.getUTCDate();
  var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
  this.schedule.date_admission = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

si sabes que todas las fechas que te genera el Datepicker tienen el mismo formato, puedes usar la siguiente función antes de realizar la operación de guardado debase de datos.

La operación slice te retonar el string cortado en un rango específico, en este caso lo que necesitas es que se incluya el string desde la posición 0 hasta la 9, como el valor de fin de slice es exclusivo ponemos un 10, que es el índice en donde se encuentra el caracter "T".

```js
let originalDate = "2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z";

function filterDate(date) {
  return date.slice(0, 10);
}

console.log(filterDate(originalDate));
```